How to achieve conditional rendering in Angular
I have this code and I want to display speakers whose role is SPEAKER in different section on the same page and those whose role is MODERATOR, and ORGANIZER in different sections on the same page without duplicating the template.


<mat-list *ngIf="!loading">
    <div *ngIf="speakers.length > 0">
      <div mat-subheader id="speakers">Speakers</div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="attendees.length > 0">
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let speaker of speakers">
          <img default="default" matListAvatar [src]="
              generateAvatar(
                speaker?.image || speaker?.AppUser?.image,
                speaker?.first_name || speaker?.AppUser?.first_name
              )
            " alt="..." />
          <div mat-line [style.display]="'flex'">
            <div class="fill-remaining-space">
              <div class="overflow">
                {{
                (speaker?.first_name || speaker?.AppUser?.first_name || "") +
                " " +
                (speaker?.last_name ||
                speaker?.AppUser?.last_name ||
                "~Anonymous") | titlecase
                }}
              </div>
              <!--            <div class="overflow"-->
              <!--                 [style.fontSize.em]="0.8">{{speaker?.title || speaker?.AppUser?.title || '~Anonymous Title'}}</div>-->
              <div class="like-comment-section">
                <app-like-btn (click)="likePerson(speaker, 'speaker')" [liked]="speaker.myLike > 0"></app-like-btn>
                <span class="like-text">{{
                  speaker.likesCount | i18nPlural : likeMapping
                  }}</span>
                <span (click)="viewSpeakerComments(speaker)" class="comment-section"><i
                    class="ui comments icon"></i></span>
                <span (click)="viewSpeakerComments(speaker)" class="comment-text">{{
                  speaker.commentsCount | i18nPlural : commentMapping
                  }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button [matMenuTriggerData]="{
                  speaker: speaker,
                  attendee: speaker?.AppUser,
                  type: 'speaker'
                }" mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="attendeeMenu" aria-label="Attendee Menu">
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </mat-list-item>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </mat-list>



This is the response to my request:


Please share your response as JSON snippet in the question. Also, please clarify the problem/issue encountered. Thanks.

You can extract everything that you need to represent a speaker into a component. And then, use that component wherever you want. I mean: everything under <mat-list-item> could be in a let's say SpeakerComponent (you can generate one using ng g component. Then, use <app-speaker [speaker]="speaker" /> every time you want to display information about a speaker. Indeed you could later loop through different categories, get each of those speakers and use the component to display those.
